# Change HTML page title to calculated column for custom list

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, calculated-column, display-form

I have a custom list called `Customers` which contains, columns `First Name`, `Last Name` and `Full Name`. `Full Name` is a calculated column which concatenates the first and last name values.

Currently, when you click on any customer in the list to view the item, the HTML title for the page is `Customers - {Last Name}`. However, what I would like to do, is to change it to `Customers - {Full Name}`.

How do I change the HTML title for the `Default Display Form` for the `Customers` list only?

Comment: Are you using a modal dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lastname field must be the title field of the list you have repurposed. This is because the PlaceHolderPageTitle content placeholder on the list's dispform.aspx uses Title field as the default.

You can change it easily using SP Designer. Open the Dispform.aspx for the list and make the below replacement on the existing PlaceHolderPageTitle field:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
<SharePoint:ListProperty Property="Title" runat="server"/> - <SharePoint:ListItemProperty Property="Full_x0020_Name" id="ID_ItemProperty" maxlength="40" runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
```

Save the page in designer and you should see the change on the list item display page.